# Qml-Why is the Text content reduced?

Tags: qt, qml

the code is

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Text {
        id: name
        text: qsTr("cesssssssss")
        font.pointSize: 10.5
        font.family: "微软雅黑"
        topPadding: 10
        bottomPadding: 10
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
    }
}
```

the result is

[image]

Why is the letter c truncated?
If i change font.pointSize to another value, it will display normal.

Comment: Hmm... works fine on mac.

Comment: Are you sure you set the font name correctly?

Comment: Try adding `anchors.left: parent.left` to your `Text` and remove the `horizontalAlignment` property assignment.

Comment: @TrebuchetMS，I know how to avoid it, but I want to know why.

Comment: @folibis,yeah,In the Chinese system, it is correct

Comment: You didn't set neither size nor anchors for `Text`. And the text is centered, but you don't know where that center is.

Comment: @SergeiOusynin,i don't think so,because I change font.pointSize to another value, it will display normal.Even if I don't set the size or anchors.

Comment: You can place colored `Rectangle` with `anchors.fill: parent` inside your `Text` to see how it actually looks

Comment: @SergeiOusynin,I added the following code to Text,        `Component.onCompleted: {
            console.log("implicitWidth",implicitWidth)
        }`,and it display normal,Can you explain it?